# I'm trying to make a password generetor using Python 3.7. I searched online how to use sample() but for me it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, sample, password-generator

So i want it to pick a random digit from a list 2 times nd then mix it together in order to get a password. I wanted the ready_password to print a list and it works but, it also prints [] and ''. So i decided to make it a tuple but i don't know how to mix a tuple. This is the error that I'm getting:

```
TypeError: sample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
```

code-

```
import random

lower_case = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 
'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

upper_case = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 
'R', 
'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

punctuation = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']

lower1 = random.choice(lower_case)
lower2 = random.choice(lower_case)

upper1 = random.choice(upper_case)
upper2 = random.choice(upper_case)

number1 = random.choice(numbers)
number2 = random.choice(numbers)

punctuation1 = random.choice(punctuation)
punctuation2 = random.choice(punctuation)

password_not_ready = (lower1 + lower2 + upper1 + upper2 + number1 + number2 + punctuation1 + 
punctuation2)

ready_password = random.sample(password_not_ready)

print(ready_password)
```

Comment: You're missing a 2nd parameter to the random.sample() call.  According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html,  sample() requires two parameters, population and k.  You've only provided the population parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `random.shuffle()` to mix up the characters instead of having them in order:

```
from random import sample as sp
from random import shuffle as sh

lower_case = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

upper_case = lower_case.upper()

numbers = '1234567890'

punctuation = '!@#$%^&*('

ready_password = sp(lower_case,2)+sp(upper_case,2)+sp(punctuation,2)+sp(numbers,2)

sh(ready_password)

print(''.join(ready_password))
```

Output:

```
c3D#0hV%
```

Answer (score 1):

`sample()` takes 2 arguments, the second being the length of the list to return, however I think what you meant to do was use `shuffle()`, to reorder all the randomly picked characters (sample will not shuffle the list). Change this line

```py
ready_password = random.sample(password_not_ready)
```

to

```py
ready_password = random.shuffle(password_not_ready, len(password_not_ready))
```

See the documentation for [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and for [sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement-
if you want to use `random.sample` you need to pass the second param k (length of the random sample from the `password_not_ready`.
so using

```
ready_password = random.sample(password_not_ready, k) #k is the desire length of the sample
print(ready_password)
```

with your existing code should work.

Links - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-random-sample-function/
https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: Thanks. Thanks for the link by the way

Answer (score 1):

K=8 for 8 digit password

```
import random
lower_case = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
upper_case = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
punctuation = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(']

lower1 = random.choice(lower_case)
lower2 = random.choice(lower_case)
upper1 = random.choice(upper_case)
upper2 = random.choice(upper_case)
number1 = random.choice(numbers)
number2 = random.choice(numbers)
punctuation1 = random.choice(punctuation)
punctuation2 = random.choice(punctuation)
password_not_ready = (lower1 + lower2 + upper1 + upper2 + number1 + number2 + punctuation1 + punctuation2)

ready_password = random.sample(password_not_ready, k=8)
print(ready_password)
```

Comment: Nice I didn’t realize that